# Prometheus: Query to find status of last 100/fixed requests?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

We have a requirement where we want to find the result of last 100 requests, Now this is where I am stuck, How can we count always fixed set of requests, if metrics look like below:

```
app_response_status{app="sampleApp", request_method="GET", api="/employee", status="200"} 20
app_response_status{app="sampleApp", request_method="GET", api="/employee", status="500"} 20
```

Or is this expectation itself is incorrect as Prometheus runs on the basis of time. We have to build the dashboard in Grafana, so if something which can be utilised in Grafana will work as well. New to Prometheus and Grafana, so please excuse me for stupidity if that's the case here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you will not be able to achieve that with Prometheus / Grafana. As you have said Prometheus is based on time series. What you want requires a log / event based approach.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, having same theory but wanted to confirm. Thanks